# Extract tabular like Data from PDF which is not in Tables

Tags: pdf, extract

i have a pdf whihc has plain text data which is kind of similar to tabular data but actually in pdf its not in actual tables.
i need to extract this data from all pages and finally put them in tables in excel.
like i need to extract this data from "Name" tag and its value till "Decrement" tag and its value and than create a excel table for same.

i tried using packages like pypdf, pdfminer etc but unable to get desired output.

but output is not desirable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKMIR.jpg)